# Remove duplicate data using bash, sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I search for duplicate data using batch, sed or awk?
Goal is to remove duplicate "Changelist: XXXXX" entry from data.txt file.
I'm kind of stuck, can somebody help me?

Please take a look at output.txt for desired output.

data.txt

```
====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview: 
 CodeReview: Result: @result___
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808273
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: B
 ShortDescr: Hello

 CodeReview: Result: 
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808271
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: C
 ShortDescr: HI

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview: 
 CodeReview: Result: @result___
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808273
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: B
 ShortDescr: Hello

 CodeReview: Result:  
 ====================================
  Changelist: 808277
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: D
 ShortDescr: HEY

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
```

output.txt

```
    ====================================
     Changelist: 808298
     Date: 2015/03/19
     Developer: A
     ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

     CodeReview: 
     CodeReview: Result: @result___
     ====================================
     Changelist: 808273
     Date: 2015/03/19
     Developer: B
     ShortDescr: Hello

     CodeReview: Result: 
     ====================================
     Changelist: 808271
     Date: 2015/03/19
     Developer: C
     ShortDescr: HI

     CodeReview: 
     ====================================
      Changelist: 808277
     Date: 2015/03/19
     Developer: D
     ShortDescr: HEY

     CodeReview: 
     ====================================


glen's output.txt

 ====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview:
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808273
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: B
 ShortDescr: Hello

 CodeReview:
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808271
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: C
 ShortDescr: HI

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
  Changelist: 808277
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: D
 ShortDescr: HEY

 CodeReview: 
 ====================================
 Changelist: 808298
 Date: 2015/03/19
 Developer: A
 ShortDescr: Checking in the following graphics:

 CodeReview:
 ====================================$sep
```

Comment: Do you mean bash, not batch?

Comment: i'm sorry, yes that's what i meant.

Comment: Do you want to keep the first one found? Or the last one?

Comment: Keep first one found..

Comment: are you sure the data sharing the same `ChangeList` will be extactly the same?

Comment: for example  "Changelist: 808298" matched, data inside of that matched block will always be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a very common task with awk

```
sep='====================================\n'
awk -F'\n' -v RS="$sep" -v ORS="$sep" '!seen[$1]++' data.txt > output.txt
```

Here, we're using the `$sep` as the awk **record** separator to read the paragraphs, and newline as the **field** separator

`!seen[$1]++` is an expression that is only true for the first record where this particular field 1 is encountered. Since no action is given, the default action is to print the current record, with the output record separator appended.

Comment: glenn thanks for quick response. but it didn't remove that duplicate block.

Comment: hmm, did for me. What's your OS?

Comment: i'm running on windows

Comment: it seems your environment didn't perform extension. are you running some kind of shell?

Comment: I think that single quotes have no special meaning, so try changing all single quotes to double quotes

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you very much --> windows --> set sep="====================================\n"
awk -F"\n" -v RS="%sep%" -v ORS="%sep%" "!seen[$1]++" output.txt > output1.txt